# Macbook Pro unable to boot and other strange internal drive behaviour

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, startup, apfs

I don't know how/why this happened, but my Macbook Pro 13" (Retina, Mid 2014) running macOS Mojave will no longer boot from the internal drive.

When I boot into internet recovery, sometimes the internal drive shows up in Disk Utility / `diskutil`, and sometimes it does not. Sometimes it will appear for a short while, and then disappear. It's very strange. Below are some pictures I took of the output of various `diskutil` commands that I hope will help to diagnose the issue. Thank you.

#### `diskutil list`

[image]

#### `diskutil info disk0` and `diskutil info disk0s1`

Note that disk0s1 could not be found on this occasion but the next image shows the output on another occasion when it could be found.

[image]

#### `diskutil info disk0s1`

[image]

#### `diskutil verifyVolume disk0` and `diskutil verifyVolume disk0s1`

[image]

#### `gpt -rvv show disk0`

[image]

### Update 1 (Added EFI Partition)

Following @klanomath's comment, I have now added the missing EFI partition (see following image). However, it still does not boot.

[image]

[image]

### Update 2 (`dd` `hexdump` output)

Following @klanomath's latest comment, below is the `dd` output. Note the internal drive is disk2 now, since the thumb drive is disk0 and the APFS container within it is disk1.

```
Macbook:~ root# dd if=/dev/disk2s2 bs=512 count=1 | hexdump -Cv
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes transferred in 0.000714 secs (717023 bytes/sec)
00000000  7f 5d e8 45 c2 f8 80 dc  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.].E............|
00000010  cd 1f 29 00 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 80 00 00 00 00  |..).............|
00000020  4e 58 53 42 00 10 00 00  66 44 a6 03 00 00 00 00  |NXSB....fD......|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  5b 1e 03 74 e9 bf 40 f1  |........[..t..@.|
00000050  96 8b 04 a4 b6 98 14 05  74 0b 31 00 00 00 00 00  |........t.1.....|
00000060  ce 1f 29 00 00 00 00 00  18 01 00 00 20 6c 00 00  |..)......... l..|
00000070  8c c0 01 00 00 00 00 00  58 3e 01 00 00 00 00 00  |........X>......|
00000080  34 00 00 00 1d 20 00 00  32 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  |4.... ..2.......|
00000090  0b 20 00 00 12 00 00 00  2e 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |. ..............|
000000a0  49 a6 09 00 00 00 00 00  01 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |I...............|
000000b0  00 00 00 00 64 00 00 00  3a 79 13 00 00 00 00 00  |....d...:y......|
000000c0  23 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  25 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |#.......%.......|
000000d0  ec a0 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000100  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000110  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000120  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000130  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000140  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000160  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000170  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000190  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000200
```

Comment: Thanks, @klanomath. I've updated the post with the MBP model and also added an image to show the new partition map following the addition of the EFI partition. Unfortunately, it still shows the flashing question mark folder symbol on boot. Is there a way to find out what the default partition map should be for a 256GB drive on Mojave? Am I missing a recovery partition for example?

Comment: Can you confirm that the Mac used to boot up from the internal drive, and then suddenly stopped booting up, without any user actions on the volume? Are you able to boot sometimes, when the drive appears? Intermittent function might suggest a hardware issue: it could just be a bad connection with the SSD blade.

Comment: Thanks, @klanomath. I've now added the output of those commands to the post. from the internal drive.

Thanks benwiggy. I am never able to boot into the internal drive. It always shows a flashing question mark folder. I think the issue started happening after an upgrade but I'm really not sure about that.

Comment: @klanomath it's 10.9.5. I'm using cmd-shift-option-R to boot to the original OS as Mavericks seems to detect the drive more reliably than Catalina.

Comment: @klanomath I just booted into 10.15 recovery, however, when I do so, it spends about 5 minutes on the "Examining volumes..." screen. Then when I open Terminal and run `diskutil verifyDisk disk0`, I get "unable to find disk for disk0". This is confirmed when I run `diskutil list` and no longer see the 256GB SSD listed.

Comment: @klanomath I really appreciate your help in resolving the mess. I have Catalina installed on a relatively fast thumb drive already. The problem is, when I boot into that, I can't see the internal SSD there either.

Comment: @klanomath I don't have the tools required to open it up right now, but I can order them if you think that's my only option at this point. Is it worth `dd`ing the EFI partition from my thumb drive onto the internal SSD, or will that cause issues given that they are different OS versions?

Comment: @klanomath. I don't think so. I use another computer for work so I would say it gets below average use. Yeah, I would do it from the 10.9.5 recovery.  Is `dd`ing the EFI partition from a Catalina install a good idea though? Not sure how I could get one from a Mojave install at this point.

Comment: @BruceJohnson The superblock looks good and APFS container size (as saved in the superblock) = partition size (disk0s2):  61228134 allocation blocks (0x3A64466) * 4096/8 = 489825072 blocks(512).

Comment: @klanomath Thanks again for your help. Do you have any more ideas? Feels like the only other things on the table are (1) an issue with the EFI partition or (2) a hardware issue.

Comment: @BruceJohnson I tend to *(2) hardware issue*. But you can try EFI cloning. They have to have the same size though - you can't clone a 4k EFI (76800 * 4k-block = 314.7 MB) to a 4k-emu/512 EFI (409600 * 512block ~ 210 MB). Please remove all (or most) of your comments!